# Consideration of fields to be used in SOQL Group By

Tags: soql, describefieldresult, group-by

I have come to know that a few fields in Salesforce.com are not groupable and that we can make sure whether field is group-able or not with getDescribeSObject.

I would like to know what are the consideration for determining whether field is group-able or not.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isGroupable) on `DescribeFieldResult` is pretty clear. If this method returns `true`, you can use it in a `GROUP BY` clause.

> **isGroupable()**
>
> Returns true if the field can be included in the GROUP BY clause of a SOQL query, false otherwise. This method is only available for Apex classes and triggers saved using API version 18.0 and higher.

I have to dig for better documentation, but I know specifically that formula fields as well as boolean and rich text fields are not groupable.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Do salesforce randomly assigns isgroupable to fields or any according to fieldtype(like Number etc)

Comment: Is your question about why certain fields are groupable and others are not?

Comment: Yes. My question is about why certain fields are groupable and others are not?